# How to use Matlab embedded coder under Windows to compile for LINUX?

Tags: linux, matlab, simulink, matlab-coder, intel-atom

I'm trying to compile a Simulink algorithm to a CarPC. The CarPC is based on a Intel Atom processor and runs in LINUX. The idea is compile the Simulink code with the Matlab embedded coder to the specific target.

The problem is I don't know if I can use my Windows version of Matlab to compile the algorithm and then use it on LINUX. I mean, compile from Windows to LINUX.

Is it possible with my Matlab R2014a from Windows to the Intel Atom processor with LINUX?

Comment: It is posible to generate c code. Then you can compile it wherever you want.

Comment: But can I generate C code from my Windows computer and compile it for a LINUX embedded system?

Answer (score 0):

As @ThP said, yes you can. One option is to generate the C code on the Windows machine and then move the generated code to a machine that has a C compiler for the embedded target and compile the C code there.

Make sure that you set up the [target hardware](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/hardware-implementation-pane.html) in:

```
Simulation > Model Configuration Parameters > Hardware Implementation
```

to be compatible with your Atom processor/compiler. Also set up the model to [generate code only](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/generate-code-from-simulink.html#bsz7ylp) in:

```
Simulation > Model Configuration Parameters > Code Generation
```

if you are planning on compiling the generated code on another machine.

There is a good deal of additional information about generating code for other targets in [the Simulink Coder documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/target.html).